# Azure website suddenly responds slowly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, wcf, azure

I have a Azure website consisting of a WCF endpoint and a MVC website running on Azure. It runs on a basic medium/large tier - so no cap in CPU as Free or Basic has. This has been running perfectly for 6 months probably, with regular deployments and updates. And performance has as expected kept consistent. But now suddenly it takes forever to load the MVC website.

The flow is as follows; we receive a call via the WCF endpoint and then we direct people to a URL that is the MVC web site. All resides on same "web site" inside Azure.

The strange thing is that I can see no difference in my log files. The WCF endpoint responds as quickly as always and from what I can see the heavy lifting inside the MVC also responds as expected, but still the user is left waiting forever on the specified URL?

As said I can't see anything in the performance logs for the MVC controllers, so somehow it seems to be the https request itself that takes ages, but how do I debug or measure this?

I am in the process of getting Visual Studio 2015 to see the remote profiling that can be generated through KUDO - but somehow I don't think that the problems resides here. I am kind of blanking so any thoughts on what could be wrong and how to debug would be appreciated. Also if anyone knows that Azure has released something within the last couple of weeks that might have slowed the application down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance that you have Application Insights turned on for the MVC site? It has a feature that will track dependency calls and should be able to give you a good idea of what is taking a long time.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies/

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try to look into that!